# Need to modify a simple regex

Tags: regex

I use this regex `!\{t\}([^\{]+)\{/t\}!` to match `{t}Any string here{/t}`. Now I need to add an optional backslash in the pattern to in front of the slash to match `{t}Any string here{\/t}` as well.

Those are some pattern I tried but didn't work:

- `!\{t\}([^\{]+)\{\\?/t\}!`
- `!\{t\}([^\{]+)\{(\\)?/t\}!`
- `!\{t\}([^\{]+)\{[\\]?/t\}!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
!\{t\}([^\{]+)\{\\?/t\}!
```

to make backslash optional.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG5gV6/1)

If you're using PHP then use:

```
$re = "!\\{t\\}([^\\{]+)\\{\\\\?/t\\}!";
```

Comment: Yes man!! the secound Reguex worked. I am using PHP. But why I need to do this in PHP?

Comment: In PHP if you're using double quote for you regex then every backslash needs to be doubled up

Comment: Simple quote and still needed to do it... -_-